# How to create a virtual attribute in Rails ActiveRecord and use it as an orderer in separate query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails method that takes a search query and input items (active record) and returns the filtered items (and with items.where() also returns an activeRecord relation)

```
def search(items)
   filtered_items = execute("select items.id from items
            inner join products ...
            left join users ...
            left join metadata ...
            where LOWER(
              coalesce(items.title, '') ||
              coalesce(accounts.title, '') ||
              like '%search_query%'
            ")
items.where(id: filtered_items)
end
```

I have another method which should sort the items by conditions:

```
def sort(items)
   filtered_items = execute("select items.id from items
            inner join products ...
            left join users ...
            left join metadata ...
            where LOWER(
              coalesce(items.title, '') ||
              coalesce(accounts.title, '') ||
              like '%search_query%'
            case when coalesce(items.title, '') like '%search_query' then 1
                 when coalesce(accounts.title, '') like '%search_query' then 2
            ..
            ... ( more conditions to decide the sorting precedence )
            end
            ")

items.where(id: filtered_items)
end
```

I would like to remove this duplication and instead do something like this:

```
def search(items)
   filtered_items = execute("select items.id,
          case when coalesce(items.title, '') like '%search_query' then 1
                 when coalesce(accounts.title, '') like '%search_query' then 2
            ..
            ... ( more conditions to decide the sorting precedence )
          end Orderer,
            from items
            inner join products ...
            left join users ...
            left join metadata ...
            where LOWER(
              coalesce(items.title, '') ||
              coalesce(accounts.title, '') ||
              like '%search_query%'
            ")
items.where(id: filtered_items)
end
```

and then:

```
def sorter(items)
  items.order("items.orderer")
end
```

so my question is:

1. is it possible to separate this kind of sorting from one query to another while still working with activeRecord ?
2. can it be implemented by using a virtual attribute (orderer) - and how so ?

Note: there is a different flow for the filters and the sorters in the system so it cant all be done in one query. (after chaining all the filters, there is a sorter that takes input items and needs to sort them via the selected strategy)

Comment: Why are you doing two queries (the `execute` and a separate `items.where(id: filtered_items)`)? You could do all that through the ActiveRecord query builder then you could directly ORDER BY your SQL CASE expression.

Comment: Because in the system there two different flows: the filters and the sorters. After all filters are done, the sorter is coming to the picture. So they all must be separate and independent, sharing similar interface and working with activeRecords only

Comment: Regarding the items.where -> it doesnt have significant affect on the performance. And the activeRecord builder is less flexible than raw queries? But you've got a point there